# scrapy 429 error and 503 error

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using the scrappy framework for the data that I want. Some of the requests are getting served but after few requests I receive status code  503 and sometimes 429.

I used the following settings:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 2.0
```

I changed the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` from 1.0 to 5.0. If I increase more, it will affect my need. What are the correct settings?

My scrappy version IS Scrapy == 1.1.1, fake-useragent == 0.1.7, Twisted == 16.3.0.

Comment: It's very possible that server banned you for short time intervals, all firewalls have rules that ban ips that exceed a specific number of requests per specific time

Comment: Thanks @ mirhossein, But how can i handle this situation. suggestions are  excepted .

Comment: It seems that site has very strict rate limiting, you can use Tor to change your ip, more instruction here https://medium.com/@mrt.kousha/implement-tor-middleware-for-anonymous-web-scraping-6f6ab33e48fa, Could you give me the site address?

Comment: Thanks , but i am using Crawlera, as they rotate the proxies for me !, do i can improve any more !

Comment: Crawlera works well for me

Comment: Do we have any difference in simple request methods and scrappy request methods . based on this sites can differentiate the requests to serve ?

Comment: I didn't understand

Comment: As i am requesting with the simple python requests i am able to get the data , but if the same request is sent through spider  i am not able to get the response.